# Unable to compile a c program in Codeblocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have installed codeblocks in windows 8 first time and try to run a simple C program but I get this error?

```
"can't find compiler executable in your search path (GNU GCC compiler)"
```

I tried many things to solve it but unable to compile.

Comment: no error, didn't happen

Comment: Oh, that's easy. If you get *this error*, you use *this* to fix it.

Comment: codeblock normally will set the compiler, which compiler you set? `gcc` windows version?

Comment: Sorry for previous mistake ..... i just completely forgot to mention ERROR.

Comment: Where did you install your GNU C compiler?  Is that location in your PATH?  Codeblocks doesn't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of encountered this problems long before.. when I was still using Windows and the Air-Quality in Beijing was still good at that time.

A problem code-blocks have, is that it might not find the proper C code compiler for you automatically. One think you can do.. is to go to the `options`(or something like that), and look for the `compiler option`, and it have some settings for you to set the compiler.

If you cannot find a proper compiler, I usually go install wxDev and use the wxDev's gcc in Code::Blocks.

Hope that helps :)